# find latest object ion DB and update array - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi im having issue updating a objects using mongoose with node.js.

i have this code to add an exercise to each object in the mongodb...

```
app.put("/index", function(req,res){
    Exe.update({}, {$push: req.body.exe}, {multi: true},  function(err, numAffected){ //NEED TO PUSH 0'S INTO ARRAYS WHEN CREATING NEW WORKOUT.
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(numAffected);
            res.redirect("/index/new");
        }
    });    
});
```

The above works and it does indeed add a single exercise to each exercise object array. The next part which im stuck on is also adding a starting number to previous weight key in the object. im using the following code:

```
app.put("/index", function(req,res){
    Exe.update({}, {$push: {req.body.exe}, {"previous" : [0]}}, {multi: true},  function(err, numAffected){ //NEED TO PUSH 0'S INTO ARRAYS WHEN CREATING NEW WORKOUT.
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(numAffected);
            res.redirect("/index");
        }
    });    
});
```

What im trying to do is let the user add an exercise which is then added to the db along with setting the previous (starting weight) to 0.

Answer (score 0):

So its seems i run into issues when using body parser and then my own arrays. i got roudn this issue with the following code:

> app.put("/index", function(req,res){
>       Exe.update({}, {$push: req.body.exe}, {multi: true},  function(err, numAffected){ 
>           if (err){
>               console.log(err);
>           }else{
>               Exe.update({}, {$push: {"previous" : 0}}, {multi: true},  function(err, numAffected){
>                   if (err){
>                       console.log(err);
>                   }else{
>                       res.redirect("/index");
>                   }
>               });
>           }
>       }); });